# Get rid of the old ADCS tag and either merge with attitude-control or attitude-determination-and-control?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

We have had the old [adcs](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adcs) tag since October 2016 and I think I created it. The acronym is for Attitude Determination and Control System.

Random links legitimizing the acronym

- [Attitude Determination and Control System (ADCS)](https://www.tudelft.nl/lr/organisatie/afdelingen/space-engineering/space-systems-engineering/research/miniaturization/attitude-determination-and-control-system-adcs)
- [ADCS: Attitude Determination And Control System](http://www.ece3sat.com/cubesatmodules/adcs/)
- [System Specifications for Attitude Determination and Control System](http://www.ece3sat.com/pdf/System_Specifications_ADCS_+_SOA.pdf)

However from faa.gov's [4.3.1 Space Vehicle Control Systems](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/media/III.4.3.1_Space_Vehicle_Control_Systems.pdf):

> We’ll begin our discussion of the space vehicle’s attitude and orbit control subsystem (AOCS) by focusing on the attitude part of the problem. Attitude defines a vehicle’s orientation in space. For example, if we want a spacecraft to take pictures of a particular spot on Earth, we need to align the payload so it points at the spot. In this case, we’d need to control the spacecraft’s attitude so it points “down,” toward Earth. In space terms, we say, “down toward Earth” is the nadir direction. The opposite direction, away from Earth toward space, is the zenith direction.
>
> Similarly, launch vehicles need to control their attitude to steer into the correct orbit and keep forces aligned along the long axis where they are strongest. However, in this section, we’ll focus mainly on the unique problems for spacecraft. **Because this function is so important, it is sometimes given a separate name—attitude determination and control subsystem (ADCS).** In this section, we’ll refer to it by that name. Regardless of the name given to the subsystem, its job is the same—keep its spacecraft pointed in the right direction

---

**Question::**

Now I wonder if the term ADCS might be *overly specific* and *insufficiently recognizable* for a good tag, and should be *retired* and either:

1. merged with the newly coined [attitude-control](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attitude-control) tag which is only a few weeks old. The new tag seems more intuitive, or
2. both merged into a new tag `attitude-determination-and-control` which was probably too long to be allowed in 2016 but [I have just tested it](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52015/12102) and it is no longer too long.

Comment: ADCS would help those who search for it, but it seems very specific, so probably helpful only to very few. I actually like attitude-determination-and-control a lot. I know if I saw it on the list of available tags, I would select it over attitude-control. It's broader in scope, but not so broad as to be useless (to search for everything is to search for nothing :D). So I like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>(Copying user39728_i_said_user_39728_i_'s [comment](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/get-rid-of-the-old-adcs-tag-and-either-merge-with-attitude-control-or-attitude-d#comment6594_1800) to an answer to allow votes.)</sup>

ADCS would help those who search for it, but it seems very specific, so probably helpful only to very few. I actually like attitude-determination-and-control a lot. I know if I saw it on the list of available tags, I would select it over attitude-control. It's broader in scope, but not so broad as to be useless (to search for everything is to search for nothing :D). So I like it.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Yes I agree with your conclusion.

Comment: @uhoh Merge complete! Don't forget to add a tag excerpt if you feel confident writing one.

Comment: Thanks! I've added something, but now [Should we clean up and separate 'attitude' and 'attitude-determination-and-control' questions, or just further merge these last two tags?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1802/12102) I suppose I should have caught this overlap the first time; my bad.