# Should we clean up and separate 'attitude' and 'attitude-determination-and-control' questions, or just further merge these last two tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging, retagging

Thanks to the [retiring of the adcs tag](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1801/12102) we now have:

[attitude](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attitude) **211** questions:

> Questions on ascertaining, predicting, and controlling spatial orientation and rotation of spacecraft, and on forces that affect spatial orientation.

[attitude-determination-and-control](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attitude-determination-and-control) **99** questions:

> Sensors, systems, strategies, algorithms and mathematics relating to BOTH determining AND controlling the attitude (3D orientation) of spacecraft.

I'd originally thought that the attitude tag was for questions only about attitude and did not contain questions *about it's control* so there was still a distinction, however the two following fancy searches show that the separation of usage between the two tags may not be clean:

- [[attitude] -[attitude-determination-and-control] control is:question](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Battitude%5D+-%5Battitude-determination-and-control%5D+control+is%3Aquestion) returns **84** question posts that have the attitude tag but not the attitud-determination-and-control tag but yet still contain the word "control".

The first few returned are *clearly about control:*

- [How powerful are ***reaction control wheels***?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10622/12102)
- [***Attitude control*** with cold gas thrusters](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50890/12102)
- [Time scale separation and cascading ***control loops***](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41584/12102)
- [Dragon launch escape: ***roll control?***](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51587/12102)
- [How to select/design a control algorithm for spacecraft ***attitude control?***](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18192/12102)

I see two very different strategies for resolving this.

1. Heavy-duty, wholesale retagging of hundreds of questions, either by laborious reading and manual retagging or by [experimental script-o-magic or temporary botification](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1757/12102)
2. A second, further merging of these two tags into attitude-determination-and-control.

The first is intriguing but I fear it will be impossible to maintain, future question authors may randomly choose one or the other, though it could be reduced by careful rewriting of the usage guidance.

**Question:** Should we clean up and separate 'attitude' and 'attitude-determination-and-control' questions, or just further merge these last two tags?

Comment: That's a lot of questions to go through.  Are you volunteering to do this work, or expecting the moderators to do it?

Comment: @DrSheldon certainly not! That's precisely why option #1 suggests *scripted automation* and why option #2 is proposed as an alternative. Don't forget to read the whole question before commenting. title≠question

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted this, but now that I've had time to think about it, I'm not entirely sure it's necessary. The tag [attitude](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attitude) is not *inappropriate* on those questions, and the tag [attitude-determination-and-control](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attitude-determination-and-control) has enough questions on its own that it's not in need of a boost.

Obviously, it would be ideal if those questions had [attitude-determination-and-control](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attitude-determination-and-control), at least in addition to [attitude](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attitude), but I'm not sure the boost to searchability is worth the effort. Especially since if we did this an automated way, it would really only be retagging those questions that are already pretty searchable without the tag.

Comment: It's not that "attitude" usage is *inappropriate*, it's that the two tags seem to be being used *interchangeably;* that there's no clear distinction between the questions tagged one way with the questions tagged the other, or with both. If the *raison d'etre* for the tags is to assist search, then splitting up the same kind of question between two different tags can be counterproductive.

Comment: I'll take more time this weekend and look through them *en masse* to confirm if this is the case or not.

Comment: "this weekend" now equals *this weekend...*